# Slow MongoDB query causing 100% CPU spike

Tags: c#, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, optimization

I would like to make a query with `MongoDB`, linking my `friends` and `user` collection.
The name of each friend the user has.

At first, I was doing it manually, and if the user had a small number of friends, it worked, but if he had a large number of friends (10,000 for example), it would crash or take a long time to process.

That's why I thought that using `$lookup` from `MongoDB` would be the best way, so that it would be processed by the database and it would go faster. Except that this doesn't solve the problem, because the `CPU goes up to 100%`, and the request takes a long time to be processed (86 088 ms for friends1 and 86 100 ms for friends2). Maybe what I did is not optimized?

What I did before is in comment.

```js
const { friendModel } = require("../Utils/Shemas.js");
const { buildXML } = require("../Utils/Util.js");

exports.data = {
  SOAPAction: "GetFriendListWithName",
  needTicket: true,
  levelModerator: 0
};

exports.run = async (request, ActorId) => {
  // const friends = await friendModel.find({ RequesterId: ActorId, Status: 1 });
  // const friends1 = await friendModel.find({ ReceiverId: ActorId, Status: 1 });
  
  let startD = Date.now();
  
  const friends1 = await friendModel.aggregate([
    { $match: {
      RequesterId: ActorId,
      Status: 1
    }},
    { $lookup: {
      from: "users",
      localField: "ReceiverId",
      foreignField: "ActorId",
      as: "user"
    }}
  ]);
  
  console.log(`Friends1: ${Date.now() - startD} ms`); // 86 088 ms
  
  const friends2 = await friendModel.aggregate([
    { $match: {
      ReceiverId: ActorId,
      Status: 1
    }},
    { $lookup: {
      from: "users",
      localField: "RequesterId",
      foreignField: "ActorId",
      as: "user"
    }}
  ]);
  
  console.log(`Friends2: ${Date.now() - startD} ms`); // 86 100 ms
  
  // console.log(friends1);
  // console.log(friends2);
    
  let FriendData = [ ];
  
  for (let friend of friends1) {
    FriendData.push({
      actorId: friend.user[0].ActorId,
      name: friend.user[0].Name
    });
  }
  
  for (let friend of friends2) {
    FriendData.push({
      actorId: friend.user[0].ActorId,
      name: friend.user[0].Name
    });
  }
  
  /*
  for(let f = 0; f < friends.length; f++) {
    const { ActorId, Name } = await userModel.findOne({ ActorId: friends[f].ReceiverId });
    FriendData.push({ actorId: ActorId, name: Name });
  };
  
  for(let j = 0; j < friends1.length; j++) {
    const { ActorId, Name } = await userModel.findOne({ ActorId: friends1[j].RequesterId });
    FriendData.push({ actorId: ActorId, name: Name });
  };
  */
      
  return buildXML("GetFriendListWithName", {
    FriendData: FriendData 
  });
};
```

Can you help me please? Thank you in advance for your answers!

Comment: How your documents looks like , do you have indexes created on the lookup fields?

Comment: Hi @R2D2, no, I'm not sure how this works.
Can you please give me an example of what would make the most sense?

Comment: db.collection.findOne() , db.collection.getIndexes() from friends & user collections can throw some light ...